# unity firebase database retrieving data

Tags: java, c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

how to get the proper way or ShortCut or fastest way retrieving data of particular child from the firebase

```
baseRef.Child ("wordRun").Child("Players").Child(userid).Child("GameRun").Child("usercount").GetValueAsync ();
```

I try like something:-
example 1

```
var getTask =baseRef.Child ("wordRun").Child("Players").Child(userid).Child("GameRun").Child("usercount").GetValueAsync ();

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => getTask.IsCompleted || getTask.IsFaulted);

        if (getTask.IsCompleted) {
            Debug.Log(getTask.Result.Value.ToString());
        }
```

example 2:-

```
baseRef.Child("wordRun").Child("Players").Child(userid).Child("GameRun").Child("usercount").GetValueAsync .ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsFaulted) {
                        // Handle the error...
                    }
                    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                      DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                      foreach ( DataSnapshot user in snapshot.Children){
                        IDictionary dictUser = (IDictionary)user.Value;
                        Debug.Log ("" + dictUser["usercount"]);
                      }
                    }
          });
```

I want to get values write a single line in firebase database if anyone knew how got value in a single line in firebase then please give answer thank you for reading...

And Please Give me a way to get all data back in a class by getting GetRawJsonValue

Comment: What is basRef equal to? Also what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 

'DatabaseReference baseRef;



FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl ("https://YOUR APP ID.firebaseio.com/");



  
baseRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;'

Comment: @PeterHaddad it goes infinite loop and crash the unity

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: you need to getting the by loop



foreach (var childSnapshot in args.Children)
{
    Debug.Log("ChildSnapshot"+childSnapshot..GetRawJsonValue());
}

Answer (score 2):

you need to getting by the loop

```
foreach (var childSnapshot in args.Children) { 

Debug.Log("ChildSnapshot"+childSnapshot..GetRawJsonValue());

}
```

and if you have any Class which have same data format then you try this

```
ClassName ClassObjectName = JsonUtility.FromJson<ClassName>(args.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
```